# .net compact framework deserialization

Tags: xml, serialization, compact-framework, custom-attributes

I have a .net 4 class which it's decorated with a ReadOnly attribute.
I'm trying to serialize this class in .NET Compact 3.5 project, but I'm getting an error:
"There was an error reflecting type IpSettings"
As far as I know .NET CF doesn't include any custom attributes, but I don't need to serialize this attribute. Is there any way to skip the attribute serialization ?
Thanks,
Alex

```
public class IpSettings
    {
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public string IP { get; set; }
```

`public string Mask { get; set; }

    public string Gateway { get; set; }

    public string DNS1 { get; set; }

    public string DNS2 { get; set; }

}`

var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(IpSettings));

Answer (score 0):

You can control xml serialization via attributes in the .NET CF. To have the serialization system ignore a property, you can decorate it with the XmlIgnore attribute:

```
public class IpSettings
{

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string IP { get; set; }


    public string Mask { get; set; }

    public string Gateway { get; set; }

    public string DNS1 { get; set; }

    public string DNS2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I want to serialize IP property, but without [ReadOnly(true)] attribute. [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore] will completely ignore IP property from serialization.

Comment: Sorry Alex. I completely mis-interpreted what you were asking. I'm not sure why you need what you're asking though, as xmlserialization doesn't serialize any object meta-data such as attributes.

Comment: the problem I belive it's not with serialization, but with reflection.
When XmlSerializer try to reflect IpSettings class , it's failing, because in .net CF there is not attribute as [ReadOnly]. This it's my guess.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how you can even load that type into a .NET CF application, as you should get a compile error. If you're loading it all dynamically somehow, can you put a pre-processor directive on your class implementation around that attribute (i.e. #IF !POCKET_PC [ReadOnly(true)] #endif

Comment: Hmm...I this you just gave me an ideea with pre-processor directive !

Answer (score 0):

I've found I often have to rethink how I approach a problem when trying to see how I will tackle something for the Compact Framework.

Consider something like the following code. It still allows your string `IP` value to be *readonly*:

```
public class IpSettings
{

    private string ip;

    public IpSettings()
    {
    }

    public IpSettings(string ipAddress)
    {
      ip = ipAddress;
    }

    public string IP { get { return ip; } }

    public string Mask { get; set; }

    public string Gateway { get; set; }

    public string DNS1 { get; set; }

    public string DNS2 { get; set; }

    public static IpSettings Load() {
      var ipSetting = new IpSettings();
      // code to load your serialized settings
      ipSettings.ip = // some value you just read
      return ipSettings;
    }

}
```

This will give you, as the programmer, flexibility in your class while still maintaining the *readonly* attributes of your `IP` field.